# ModelandView doesnt work

Tags: spring-mvc

I created registration Controller. Everything works fine, user is create in database but then end service program doesnt go to successRegister view. I dont know why. If I return like String successRegister everything is ok.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView registerUserAccount(@RequestBody @Valid User accountDto,
                                            BindingResult result, WebRequest request, Errors errors) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("successRegister", "User", accountDto);
        }

        User registered = userService.register(accountDto);
        if (registered == null) {
            result.rejectValue("email", "message.regError");
        }
        try {
            String appUrl = request.getContextPath();
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent
                    (registered, request.getLocale(), appUrl));
        } catch (Exception me) {
            return new ModelAndView("successRegister", "User", accountDto);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("successRegister");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with AJAX. I changed location after success and then ModelAndView was not return.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this

> produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

You says produces a JSON response but thats not true, you want to return a ModelAndView, so try to remove that attribute